Choose CPU processor (intel or AMD) of machine hosting action runner
Besides choosing between linux/windows/mac and 32/64 bit, is it possible to choose the processor of the machine where the action runner will be running? In my organization we have been using actions smoothly, but a partner of ours, compiling and using our code, reports runtime crashes when running on a AMD machine.
We are waiting for more information from their side: we don't know whether they compiled on an intel machine and then tried running on an AMD machine, or if both compilation and execution where on an AMD machine
In the meantime, to try and reproduce his problem we were wondering whether it would be possible to force the action to run on a AMD machine, and see if we experience the same crash. Locally, our computers are all intel based and cannot test the compiling here/executing there hypothesis.

For GitHub Actions, GitHub says:

For Linux and Windows runners, GitHub uses Dadsv5-series virtual machines. For more information, see Dasv5 and Dadsv5-series in the Microsoft Azure documentation.

Those pages in turn say:

Dasv5-series VMs utilize AMD's 3rd Generation EPYC™ 7763v processors that can achieve a boosted maximum frequency of 3.5GHz.


Dadsv5-series utilize AMD's third Generation EPYCTM 7763v processors that can achieve a boosted maximum frequency of 3.5GHz.

So, in short, if you don't use a self-hosted runner, at the time of writing, you should get an AMD CPU.
You can of course verify this by running e.g. lscpu in a GitHub-hosted runner.

Thank you very much! I guess the problem must be elsewhere, since we tests running in the actions were already on amd machines, and locally we were running them on intel machines
